# activating and deactivating certain paths in a drawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to make a hangman app and have created a hangman SVG file with separate paths for each of the body parts in the vector.

Is there a way to turn these paths on and off so I don't need to make several copies of the file for each stage of the hangman game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one way to do that,

Use [RichPath](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath):

1- vector_drawable.xml

```
<vector >
    <path
        ...
        android:name="path_name"
        ... />
</vector>
```

2- In your layout.

```
<com.richpath.RichPathView
    ...
    app:vector="@drawable/vector_drawable"
    ... />
```

3- Find a RichPath.

```
RichPath richPath = richPathView.findRichPathByName("path_name");
```

4- Change any attribute

```
richPath.set..();
```

for example `fillColor`, `strokeColor`, `strokeAlpha`, `fillAlpha`, `trimPathEnd`, `trimPathOffset` and more.

For more info check the [README](https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath) file.